# Importing objects in a default constructor using MEF

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, containers, mef

I really think this is not asked yet and not sure if anyone has run into this issue before

So I am working with MEF and have a class like below -

```
[Export]
public class MyClass : IBase
{
    private IEnumerable<IMyAddin> _theAddin;

    // Default constructor will NOT be
    // used because the ImportingConstructor
    // attribute is present.
    public MyClass() 
    { 
        foreach (var addin in _theAddin)
            DoSomeVeryImportantWork(addin);
    }
 
    // This constructor will be used.
    // An import with contract type IMyAddin is 
    // declared automatically.
    [ImportingConstructor] 
    public MyClass([ImportMany]IEnumerable<IMyAddin> MyAddin;) : this()
    {
        _theAddin = MyAddin;
    }
}
```

I have a method somewhere like below -

```
T GetById<T>(Guid id) where T:IBase, new()
{
    var x = new T(); 
    //Do some processing
    return x
}
```

Problem is, since I am doing a new T(), default constructor doesn't know anything about `_TheAddin` and is null.

Has anyone faced this before? Please let me know if the question is not clear, I can provide more details.

I have tried removed `[ImportingConstructor]` from the default constructor, but it doesn't work. How do I populate `_theAddin`?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: I have also tried as below, doesn't work -

```
[Export]
public class MyClass : IBase
{
    [ImportMany]
    private IEnumerable<IMyAddin> _theAddin;

    // Default constructor will NOT be
    // used because the ImportingConstructor
    // attribute is present.
    public MyClass() 
    { 
        foreach (var addin in _theAddin)
            DoSomeVeryImportantWork(addin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I am doing that. This is part of web api code and I built a container and  fed into web api IDependencyResolver.

Comment: There are several flaws in your approach. First of all, if something is a component/injectable, that needs to be auto-wired by the container, don't new it up your self. Let your container do this. Second your [component's constructor should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), so you should not some very important work in the ctor. Third, your components should [always only have 1 single constructor](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Comment: Please see my comment below @Steven. Agree with you and probably it was not the best approach to have both new() and trying to inject at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create the underlying CompositionContainer yourself and provide some static methods to retrieve objects from it. You could also expose your container directly so that you can access methods like SatisfyImportsOnce(), GetExport() etc. from anywhere.

Note: you can get rid of the ctor that does the import and decorate your private field directly with [ImportMany]. This way after creating a new T() you could call yourContainer.SatisfyImportsOnce(your_T_instance).

See the example on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! As mentioned in the other comment, this is part of Web Api code and I do have a container which is used in implementing IDependecyResolver and passed on to MVC runtime to resolve object. Not sure if I am missing something, but I don't have access to the container once assigned to DependecnyResolver outside of global.asax.

Comment: And you don't have access to the IDependencyResolver implementation either?

Comment: I have, pls see below in Global.asax
`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new MefApiDependencyResolver(container);`

Comment: Okay, then instead of var x = new T() can't you use var x = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(T)) as T ?

Comment: We changed the entire approach itself as it was not turning out logical to go in this direction. This is in line with the comment made by Steven above that if we want something injected, we shouldn't be newing up. We ended up calling the required process dynamically using reflection instead of relying on constructor to wire up things for us.

Comment: I upvoted Steven's comment, pls do the same to help out other ppl!

Comment: Just as a follow-up, wanted to mention that I ended up using Autofac for this entire thing and a great many problems just disappeared. In my opinion Autofac handles DI much better and never going back to MEF.